# Can there be a fire hose with no reaction at the outlet?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

Can there be a fire hose with no reaction at the outlet? Generally, fire hoses have reaction force, so sometimes firefighters have to grasp the hose with great force. Can there be a hose with no reaction force at the outlet?

Answer (score 2):

Forces always come in pairs, equal and opposite. If the hose exerts a force on the water that changes its direction or speed, the water exerts a force on the hose.

A fire hose has a nozzle that is carefully designed to squeeze the flow from wide and slow to narrow and fast. Fast moving water flies farther, allowing the firemen to stand back from the fire.

Firemen may turn the hose to point at different areas of the fire. The end of the hose changes the direction of the flow. The water pushes on the hose and the hose pushes on the firemen. The firemen must push back.

Comment: If it is a straight pipe with equal diameter, there will be no reaction force at the pipe outlet, right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.  It is the curvature of the hose that causes the reaction force.

Comment: @ChetMiller But in fact, it is generally believed that the outlet of straight garden hose has reaction force. Why?

Comment: The friction of the water on the inner walls of the hose "pushes" it backward, so there's still that equal and opposite reaction. Unless the hose is rigid, ie. a pipe, it will compress backward. Even a pipe will push back, only remaining still unless a stronger force (like a wall) prevents it from doing so.

Answer (score 2):

there is always a reaction force. This is why fire hose nozzles above a certain size have a specially-designed swiveling nozzle assembly which can shoot a stream of water in any desired direction while transferring the reaction force to the platform on which the nozzle is mounted, so the fire fighter does not have to manage it "personally".

Comment: You mean: if it is a straight pipe with equal diameter, there will be no reaction force at the pipe outlet, right?

Comment: No. in that case there will be a reaction force along the length of the pipe

Comment: Is there any reaction force at the pipe outlet?

Comment: Enbin, just consider the end of the pipe like a rocket nozzle.

Comment: Do you mean the pipe inlet at this end?